# CentOSに立てたApacheをホストから使う

Tags: java, centos, apache, eclipse, virtualbox

ホストOS上のEclipseで開発したJavaによるWebアプリケーションを、VirtualBox上に構築したCentOSのApacheを使って動かしたいと思っています。

ホストOS上のEclipseで開発したJavaプログラムから、VirtualBox上に構築したCentOSにインストールしたOracleに接続し、データにアクセスするところまではできました。

しかしWebサーバを利用する勝手がわかりません。

Linuxの知識というよりもEclipseの知識が重要になるのかなと思いますが、具体的な設定方法をご存知でしたら宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaのWebアプリケーションはApache HTTPサーバー上では動作しません。TomcatなどのJavaコンテナーが必要です。既にEclipseでWebアプリケーションのwarファイルが作成できているようでしたら、CentOSにTomcatをインストールしてwebappsディレクトリーにそのwarファイルをコピーして下さい。必要であれば、TomcatをApacheと連携することもできます。

以下のページが参考になると思います。

参考：
https://itsakura.com/tomcat-warfile